# How do I route a request to my EC2 instance with Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance with NGINX and Node.js app.

It has a default Public DNS and Public IP that are set by AWS on instance creation.

Public DNS: `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Public IP: `xx.xx.xxx.xx` (which is the same as in Public DNS `ec2-xx-...`)

I want to make Public DNS like this `foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. That is, simply get rid of that `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx` part and set some arbitrary word instead.

How can I do it? I'm trying to use Route53 but it doesn't make it:

[image: Image Description here]

Is it possible at all? I know I can register and use a domain name like `example.com` with Elastic IP, but in this particular case I want to set up exactly as I wrote above. I want to know if it is possible at all and if it is what do I do wrong? Should I also make changes in these files in my EC2?

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      92 Feb 20  2014 host.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      16 Apr 21 10:39 hostname
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     649 Jul 12 21:43 hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     411 Mar 25  2015 hosts.allow
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     711 Mar 25  2015 hosts.deny
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to create a custom domain like this `foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com` for your use.

The above domain is subdomain of "amazonaws.com" and you are not the owner of this domain Amazon is, so the only way is you have to buy a custom domain and map it to the EC2 instance from Route 53.

Comment: But EC2 docs says I can "*If you do not have a public DNS name registered, you can still change the hostname, but the process is a little different.*" (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html#set-hostname-system).

Comment: Yes so first scenario is assigning a custom domain "mydomain.com"  another one is changing the internal domain to local domain but in question you asked to change the "amazonaws.com" domain of the EC2 which is not possible.

Comment: I did not ask how to change `amazonaws.com` domain. I asked if it is possible to change *only* `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx` part of a Public DNS name.

Comment: Check your question you want to change "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com" to "foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com" what does that mean?